# pg_isready not installed on RHEL

Tags: postgresql, rhel8

We have an application that uses PostgreSQL 11 from Ubuntu, and the installation procedure installs the PG client tools, including pg_isready.  I'm working on converting this over to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, and am following the instructions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) to select the correct PG repo (it's telling me to use https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm). If I just use the command `sudo dnf install -y postgresql11` (rather than postgresql11-server), I get all the client tools **except** pg_isready.  I even tried installing the server package, but still no luck.

Is pg_isready part of the RHEL distribution for PostgreSQL 11?  If so, how would I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I finally found pg_isready along with the rest of the client tools installed in /usr/pgsql-11/bin.  But it appears that just a handful are added as symlinks in /usr/bin, e.g.:

`/usr/bin/psql -> /etc/alternatives/pgsql-psql -> /usr/pgsql-11/bin/psql`

Would adding /usr/pgsql-11/bin to the path create any issues?

Comment: How are determining the `pg_isready` is not installed? Have you tried to use it and if so what was the error message?

Comment: It is probably not on your `PATH`. Try `/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_isready` or add it to your `PATH`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, it was based on that it wasn't found on the path as it is with an Ubuntu install; finding it (along with other PG tools) in that other folder resolved that.

Comment: @laurenz-alba, I think that's going to be the answer; I assume putting it after /usr/bin should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the response from @laurenz-alba is the way to go (putting the directory where pg_isready and the other tools are installed in the path). Evidently the installation is just different with RHEL as compared to Ubuntu.

To resolve this, I created the file /etc/profile.d/pgcli.sh with this line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-11/bin`

This will be sourced by the system login script so any user will have the PG client tools in their path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).